# How I can auto end specific process?

Tags: ram, process

How can I auto end a specific process when it reaches 400 MB RAM? And how do I change it back after I do that ? Is there any program or script or anything ?!

Answer (score 1):

Here goes the sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here put the name of your process
ProcName="process_name"
# Here put the desired memory limit in KBytes
MemLimit=400000
ProcID=$(pidof "$ProcName")
if [ -z "$ProcID" ] ; then echo "Process not found" ; exit ; fi

while true
do
  MemCurrent=$(grep VmSize /proc/"$ProcID"/status | cut -f 2 | tr -d ' kB')
  if [ $MemCurrent -gt $MemLimit ]
  then
    kill -9 "$ProcID"
    exit
  fi
  sleep 5
done
```

Set your desired process name and memory limit in `ProcName` and `MemLimit` variables. Save this script somewhere, for example as `~/killer.sh`. Make it executable: `chmod +x killer.sh`. Then run it: `./killer.sh`.

What do you mean by "*change it back*"?

**N.B.** Actually `VmSize` will not give you exact memory usage. Calculation of real process memory usage is a complex task. You can get some insight here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303. But I think that this script will be sufficient in your case.

Comment: where can i put dat script i wrote them on wordpad file and change its ex 2 bat but it was ineffective

Comment: There is no `wordpad` in Ubuntu (at least in default installation). Wordpad and batch files are from the Windows world. Do you mean `gedit` instead? I added some more instructions to make the things more clear. As for the script - it works. I tested it. As soon as the process exceeds its `VmSize` limit, it is closed promptly.

Comment: hello sorry for disturb would u upload dat script file 2 media fire or what ever and gme da link for process name "Sro_Client.exe" on limit "400kb" and iwana know if that script works for windows 7 ultimate 64 bit

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for solution in completely wrong place. You are asking questions at askUBUNTU forum (**hint**: all questions here are UBUNTU related). Go and seek somewhere at askWINDOWS forums. I'm done.